# MYSQL Relationship....Not Clear

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

[image]

**Is this a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship?**

I think it is one-to-many as one sales rep can serve many customers. But in this select statement case, i am confused.

Comment: its nearly impossible to read SQL query text from an image; while screen snips are really easy, it makes it *much* more difficult for anyone that might want to assist you, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is.  The results seem reasonable as does the assumption that this is a one-to-many relationship.  What results are you expecting?  What is the problem?

Comment: One sales rep can serve many customers. Can a customer only have one sales rep? If so then it's one-to-many. But if a customer can have many sales reps, then it's many-to-many.

Comment: yes. they can have either 1 sales rep or none. so it is one-to-many relationship then. Thanks all for your help!